# What is nvOpzp; AND 1=1 OR (<'">iKO))?

Tags: sql-injection

I am seeing queries to a public search box on a website several times daily:

```
'nvOpzp; AND 1=1 OR (<'">iKO)),
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 7):

It's just an attempt to see if the code will error out. Two kinds of quotes just in case the other kind is not escaped. The nonsense text to look for in the output - if it's found then likely there is a possible injections.

Possibly a test for XSS too.

This code is looking for three different flaws:

- the data is not properly treated before use - escaped for HTML, prepared for SQL
- the errors are shown on the screen instead of being logged
- the adherence to the above rules is arbitrary and not mandatory

Several times a day simply because the process is mindlessly automated, a range scan. People doing that are usually called script-kiddies - knowing actually nothing they just run some premade software.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I'm still curious though.  What is nvOpzp?

Comment: "The nonsense text to look for in the output - if it's found then likely there is a possible injection"

Comment: The text is common across many servers and requests, I would be interested in knowing if there is a specific tool or threat actor that uses that string. Seems unusual that it uses the same string. sqlmap, for example, generates a random string.

Comment: I would also love to know what specific software this is, just out of interest.

Comment: Just to confirm - it is testing XSS too as you thought. Since this tool is so widespread and consistent, I added "nvOpzp" to my Request Filtering under Query Strings. While you want to make sure you aren't vulnerable to SQLi, it doesn't hurt to lock the script kiddies out of the room so you can cut down on threat traffic to sift through.

Answer (score 1):

I see these also in my server logs. They are coming from consumer networks and from cloud / server farms. I guess millions of IP addresses, so this is most likely a big player not afraid of using the same "signature" over months. Simple to detect and block, though.